# Beginner AWS Cognito concerns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am a beginner in aws coming from parse and would appreciate any help from you guys. I want to setup a user signup/ login system using aws for my Unity game.

This process will be of 2 kinds:

1. Facebook
2. Custom user signup/ login.

Regarding facebook, I managed to do it using Congnito help. But regarding Custom user sign up/ login I found I need to setup my own authentication like this : [Lambda](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth)

Question 1: Is this the only option? Is there anything like what parse provided?

Question 2: The data stored on Cognito is in datasets. Each user will have 1 dataset or 1 identity? If each user has 1 database each user will have a space of 1 MB max? I read identity contains maximum of 20 datasets. So what would happen when I have more than 20 users? A new identity would be created automatically? Also, if I want to upload user pictures, I would need S3 right? Will there be need of dynamodb to store user data?

Bear with me if my questions are very simple because I am just a beginner in aws.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use AWS Cognito service for mobile application that require custom login and custom third-party login.

Comment: I had used AWS Cognito Service with DynamoDB SDK for mobile data store. DynamoDB is NOSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Recently Cognito launched User Pools feature. This will enable you to do custom signup/login. See: [Your user pools](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-user-pools-for-amazon-cognito/)

2: An identity is a unique identifier for the end user. If you use Cognito sync to store the data, 1 identity can have 20 datasets each of max size 1 MB. You can have as many identities (end users) as you want. You can as well store data in S3 and use Cognito vended temporary and scoped credentials to access to S3 data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Cognito stores only key value pairs? Right? If I want to store more data, I should use dynamodb? For saving images/ videos, I should be using S3? Also, once cognito authenticates a user, it generates me an unique id for that user so I should use that in dynamodb. Right?

Comment: User pools is a great feature indeed. If I want to store more data such as user profile pic or some dictionaries which can be larger in size should I use dynamodb? Or s3?

Comment: - For saving images/videos, S3 might be better choice.
- For cognito federated identity you  can use the unique id in the DynamoDB/S3 in key for scoped access.
- If you are not using identity federation or sync and the data does not frequently changes. For eg: Profile picture you can  store it in S3 and store the signed URL in the custom user pool attributes.